# Prioritize scheduling restart of crashed android service

Tags: android, service, taskmanager

By using [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) , if my service is crashed/killed by task manager, it automatically restarts. I see that there are a list of services which gets restarted but in a different order. I want to prioritize this restarting of the service so that it will start sooner by placing to the front of the queue.

It typically takes 15 seconds to 45 seconds to re-start the service. Is there a way to prioritize or start this service sooner than the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your service long running? If it is, try to get rid of it and only start it when it is needed. Android services are not meant to run as a daemon, they are meant to run as short living workers in the background when no user interaction and interface is needed.

Most of the "I'm just sitting around" services can listen to broadcast intents and be a nice citizen this way.

Another thing: If your service is already short running and the a task killer is active, it's easy: It's the users problem and not your fault. The system doesn't need task killers and you shouldn't take care of them. The user should know that it's not healthy to use them.

Comment: Mine is the "Another thing". I believe I should add a message to add my app to the Task Manager ignore list.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this solution is a little bit dirty, but you could use a new Service that starts with `START_STICKY` and set all other services to `START_NOT_STICKY`.

You could then use the new service to start all other services (though this is not necessarily needed). This is actually an easy implementation, as you can pass the whole intent to the service that shall be started.

Then you could add a Broadcast on all service's `OnDestroy()` to tell the new service, that one of the old was killed by the system. You can also pass the old starting intent via `OnDestroy()`, so it gets restarted.

In case your new service gets killed, you can check after restarting if any of the other services was killed, too and then prioritize the restarting.